# How to mix PHP and JavaScript code using `echo`?

Tags: javascript, php

First of all it has been almost a week that I've started coding, so even though some essential knowledge is there, I'm still missing lots of things. I'm making a PWA and need a map echoed when someone logs in with an account. Accounts are working, getting info from databases is working so into the problem we go. First of all I'm guessing that the script inside the echo is trying to get some things from the js files but fails to do so because of probably the way the code is written. In this php code here, everything works for other map examples, but I wanted to use another more suitable map for my needs. Concluding, when I run the site, even though the whole thing loads, map doesn't show. I'm currently guessing that there is a problem with the way I use "" or '' or the import command. I've been trying for 2 days now changing things inside the code but nothing seems to be working. I hope I gave you the info you need and looking forward to your suggestions.

I've tried using " instead of ' inside script. Doesn't work cause it gets recognised as php code. Tried using additional ' to the "from" part of the import, no bueno.  Tried using heredoc, but doesn't work cause I get the "syntax error ,page has unixpected end" or some sort which probably means I'm doing it the wrong way. Have changed the " to ' insite the attributions and url links cause it was either marked as a //message or it was recognised as a "php code".
Here is the link to the map i want to use https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/xyz-esri.html

```
<?php
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE uidUsers = '" . $_SESSION['userUid'] . "'";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
  if ($resultCheck > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ){
      $lon = $row['lon'];
      $lat = $row['lat'];
      $lonlat = $lon.", ".$lat;
      echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
    import Map from 'jsc/ol/Map.js';
    import View from 'jsc/ol/View.js';
    import TileLayer from 'jsc/ol/layer/Tile.js';
    import {fromLonLat} from 'jsc/ol/proj.js';
    import XYZ from 'jsc/ol/source/XYZ.js';
    var map = new Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
          new TileLayer({
            source: new XYZ({
              attributions: 'Tiles © <a href=\"https://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/' +
                  'rest/services/World_Topo_Map/MapServer\">ArcGIS</a>',
              url: 'https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/' +
                  'World_Topo_Map/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}'
            })
          })
        ],
        view: new View({
          center: fromLonLat([$lonlat]),
          zoom: 15
        })
      });
           </script>";
    }
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: Are you expecting to match multiple user records with a single `userUid`? If not, you don't need the while loop. A single call to `mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)` will return your result.

The Javascript you are echo'ing assumes the openlayers code you're importing is available. Have you installed those packages via `npm` (npmjs.org), or placed them in a `jsc` directory next to your PHP script?

Comment: I haven't installed the packages but i have all the files needed inside my jsc folder. That's why I changed the 'ol/map.js' to jsc/ol/map.js. About the user records. I'm thinking of adding multiple results to when a user logins. For example, orestis logs in, a map shows with the location of several things around "oresti's location". The problem is not the sql and if code. I'm having issues with the echo. Whatever I do, seems like the map isn't there even though I have triplechecked the location of all the files that the script needs.

Comment: Then you'll want to change your import paths to `./jsc/ol/Map.js` (and the other imports) to import a relative file (note the `./` at the start), not look for a `jsc` package.

These import statements are supported by Google Chrome and Firefox but typically, for wider browser support you'd use a module bundler like webpack. That will produce a minified bundled JS file and you'd include that in your HTML output with a `<script>` tag

Comment: Hey Greg again. I tried your changes, but I'm still getting an empty div. Just so we're clear. The import should be like `import Map from './jsc/ol/Map.js'` ? And also is the quotation marked correctly. Did you detect any misspells or anything compared to the actual XYZ Esri code? I don't know if you have noticed but the whole thing to be working i changed quotations inside the Esri code that openlayer provided. Cause elseway i was getting a syntax error at the attributions part. If it's easy for you could you provide the correct way this thing should be written please?

Comment: I've fixed the attributions quoting in your post. See [my changes](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56019851/revisions).

Comment: Sigh... I don't get it dude. I keep getting a blank div. And I'm certain that it's not a css or coding on the div or some sort cause I've used other maps and they were working perfectly. There doesn't seem to be anything wrong codewise. Another thing to add is that I tried just copying the code from the XYZ Esri into a test.html file just to see if the thing is working as a standalone. Seems that even though I copied the code from here [openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/xyz-esri.html] the test page is blank. Nothing shows. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code. It's your same code, except, I've closed PHP code before javascript starts and reopened after javascript ends. In between for passing the variable `lonlat`, I used the notation, `<?= $lonlat ?>`.

**Note**: *This is untested code.*

```
<?php
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE uidUsers = '" . $_SESSION['userUid'] . "'";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
  if ($resultCheck > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ){
      $lon = $row['lon'];
      $lat = $row['lat'];
      $lonlat = $lon.", ".$lat;
      ?>
      <script type='text/javascript'>
    import Map from 'jsc/ol/Map.js';
    import View from 'jsc/ol/View.js';
    import TileLayer from 'jsc/ol/layer/Tile.js';
    import {fromLonLat} from 'jsc/ol/proj.js';
    import XYZ from 'jsc/ol/source/XYZ.js';
    var map = new Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
          new TileLayer({
            source: new XYZ({
              attributions: 'Tiles © <a href='https://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/' +
                  'rest/services/World_Topo_Map/MapServer'>ArcGIS</a>',
              url: 'https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/' +
                  'World_Topo_Map/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}'
            })
          })
        ],
        view: new View({
          center: fromLonLat([<?= $lonlat ?>]),
          zoom: 15
        })
      });
           </script>
    <?php
    }   // while loop ends
  } // closing if condition
  ?>
```

Comment: Hey Jacob. I tried using your changes. But unfortunately there is no result. The div is still empty without any map showing inside.

Comment: None at all. There doesn't seem to be anything wrong codewise. Another thing to add is that I tried just copying the code from the XYZ Esri into a test.html file just to see if the thing is working as a standalone. Seems that even though I copied the code from here [https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/xyz-esri.html] the test page is blank. Nothing shows.

Comment: Are you outputting the HTML outside the `<script>` tags too? As per the example

Comment: @GregK I actually did, yes. The thing is the div that contains  this code is still blank. I'm like 99% sure that it's not a div problem since i used other maps and worked perfectly. This is the one that gives me trouble. Someone could say..."ok man why don't you use another map that works then?". The answer is that this one is perfect cause except the fact that it doesn't contain shop markers and other annoying things, it also includes buildings in it in a topographic view. Tried everything. If you try to paste their code in an html, it's not working. Unless i miss something invisible.

Comment: If no users match in your query, this code will not be rendered. Can you see from the browser inspector (F12) that this code has been rendered / is in the DOM?

Comment: You can't see anything if there is no user, so this can't be wrong right now. Also at this point I'm logged in in the system. And as I've told you the certain code must have a flaw, cause everything else was working perfectly fine. And by everything else, I mean the other map examples I used in the code. So I would leave the user part outside of the question, since there is nothing wrong in it. Have created 4 accounts in the database, all work correctly and also their data(meaning lon,lat) but not for this code(meaning the XYZ Esri).

Comment: @GregK Could there be a missing js file that i need to add in the html <script> section, or even run it at the end of the page ? When I go to inspect mode in the XYZ Esri site, I see multiple scripts running. Could this be a thing ? Something hidden or wrong in this particular code, that would cause my code not to work ?

Comment: @GregK Good morning there Greg. A small update. Installed the ol package through node. So now my directories look like this `jsc/ol/node_modules/ol/Map.js` . And yes my page finishes with /body and /html in the end ...but still no results on the div.

Comment: If you're not using a module bundler, I don't think you can use the ol node package. You shouldn't have a `node_modules` directory served from your web server (within the document root). If you are seeing no errors and no map, it hints to me your JS isn't being called. Can you see network calls to fetch the files specified in your import statements? `http://<your_host>/jsc/ol/Map.js` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get this working. Used the ARCGIS map from esri along with a geojson layer to it in order to add custom features. Thanks everyone for trying.